# Laravel-Visitors Counter

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

this code repeats one IP hits every time when I visit this IP...
if I visit repeatedly with one IP hits increment, not IP increment

how can I solve this ?? can anyone guide?

```
   $date = new \DateTime;

    $check_if_exists = DB::table('visitors')
    ->where('ip',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->first();

    $get_visit_day = DB::table('visitors')->select('created_at')
    ->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->first();

   $value = date_create($get_visit_day->created_at);
    if(!$check_if_exists)
    {
        DB::table('visitors')->insert(array('ip' => 
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'hits' => '1', 'created_at' => $date));
    }else{
        DB::table('visitors')->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        ->increment('hits')->insert('updated_at', $date);
        // DB::table('visitors')->insert('updated_at', $date);
    }

    // $value = date_create($get_visit_day->created_at);
    if ($check_if_exists && date_format($value, 'd') != date('d')) {
        DB::table('visitors')->insert(array('ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'hits' => '1', 'created_at' => $date));
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: instead of using created_at and updated_at for visited date checking , take one extra column for visited_date with date type and use it for compare logic

Comment: a race condition seams to be possible here and you can add up with a ip duplication assuming you don't have a unique key on your table and two pc's or one from the same IP makes two connections at the same time and running the check and insert PHP code at the same time..

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to add new record for each day , and increment view count for every hit for today form unique ip

```
$date = new \DateTime;

    $check_if_exists = DB::table('visitors')
    ->where('ip',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->first();

    $get_visit_day = DB::table('visitors')->select('created_at')
    ->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->first();

    $is_today_if_exists = DB::table('visitors')->whereDate('created_at',$date)
    ->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->count();



    if(!$check_if_exists)
    {
        DB::table('visitors')->insert(array('ip' => 
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'hits' => '1', 'created_at' => $date));
    }
    elseif ($is_today_if_exists>0) 
    {
        DB::table('visitors')->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->whereDate('created_at',$date)
        ->increment('hits');
    }
    else
    {

        DB::table('visitors')->insert(array('ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'hits' => '1', 'created_at' => $date));
    }
```